# RecyclerView not refreshing after inserting item using Alertdialog

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have an RecycleView. i take an ArrayList for Fetch all my Category that i inserted in mySqliteDatabase. and finally i set this ArrayList into RecycleView using its Adapter.

**Problem:**

(1) First Open CategoryActivity. (no categories)
(2) Add First Category, Second, Third  no one is Refreshing.
(3) but after Adding First if i go back. and come again in that Activity. and if now i am insert Second categories then all **[next items]** are getting refresh.

My Problem is whenever i insert 1st Category. it insert successfully but it is not shown in my RecycleView or an ArrayList **[means Recycleview not refreshing].**

but my Main Problem is my RecycleView is not Refreshing only **FirstCategory** on My ArrayList.. After adding First item my next all Arraylist item is getting Refreshed.

**Below is my All Code.**

**CategoryAdapter**

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.MyViewHolder> implements Filterable {

        private ArrayList<CategoryModel> dataList;

        class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            TextView tvCategoryItem;

            MyViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                tvCategoryItem = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvCategoryName);
            }
        }

        CategoryAdapter(ArrayList<CategoryModel> dataSet) {
            this.dataList = dataSet;
            this.filterList = dataSet;
        }

        // I used this method too. but same problem.
        void refreshAdapter(ArrayList<CategoryModel> dataSet) {
            dataList.clear();
            dataList.addAll(dataSet);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.rv_row_category_list, parent, false);

            return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
            CategoryModel categoryModel = dataList.get(position);
            holder.tvCategoryItem.setText(categoryModel.getCategoryName());
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return dataList.size();
        }
    }
```

**CategoryListActivity**

```
MyDatabase myDb;
            CategoryModel categoryModel;
            RecyclerView recyclerCategory;
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
            CategoryAdapter adapter;
            ArrayList<CategoryModel> allCategory;
            int CategoryType;

            @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_category);

    myDb = new MyDatabase(this);
    recyclerCategory = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerCategory);

    CategoryType = CaseActivity.CategoryType;
    Log.d(GlobalConstant.KEY_CATEGORY_TYPE, "" + CategoryType);

    allCategory = myDb.getCategoryByType(CategoryType);

    if (allCategory.size() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No Category", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    adapter = new CategoryAdapter(allCategory);
    recyclerCategory.setAdapter(adapter);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerCategory.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerCategory.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerCategory.setHasFixedSize(true);

    recyclerCategory.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, recyclerCategory,
            new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                    TextView tvCategoryItem = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvCategoryName);
                    String CategoryName = tvCategoryItem.getText().toString();

                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    CategoryId = allCategory.get(+position).getCategoryId();
                    intent.putExtra("CategoryId", String.valueOf(CategoryId));

                    Log.e("Clicked Cat Id is ", "" + CategoryId);
                    intent.putExtra("CategoryName", CategoryName);
                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
                    finish();
                }

                @Override
                public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position) {

                }
            }
    ));
}

private void openAlert() {
    final EditText etCategoryName = new EditText(this);

    CustomAlertDialog dialog1 = new CustomAlertDialog(this);
    dialog1.setTitle("Add Category");
    dialog1.setView(etCategoryName);
    dialog1.setCancelable(true);

    dialog1.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            final String CategoryName = etCategoryName.getText().toString().trim();
            final String storedCategoryName = myDb.ExistCategory(CategoryName);

            if (CategoryName.equals("") && CategoryName.length() == 0) {
                Builder builder1 = GlobalConstant.createAlert(CategoryListActivity.this, "Warning", "Enter Category Name");
                builder1.setPositiveButton("Back", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                if (CategoryName.equals(storedCategoryName)) {
                    Builder builder1 = GlobalConstant.createAlert(CategoryListActivity.this, "Warning", "Category Already Exists");
                    builder1.setPositiveButton("Back", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            dialogInterface.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();

                    categoryModel = new CategoryModel(CategoryName, String.valueOf(CategoryType));

                    myDb.createCategory(categoryModel);

                    Toast.makeText(CategoryListActivity.this, "CategoryName " + CategoryName
                            + "\nCategoryType " + CategoryType, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    allCategory.clear();

                    allCategory = myDb.getCategoryByType(CategoryType);

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            }
        }
    });
    dialog1.show();
}

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_add:
                    openAlert();
                default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

my **createCategory()** method.

```
public long createCategory(CategoryModel categoryModel) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(CATEGORY_NAME, categoryModel.getCategoryName());
        values.put(CATEGORY_TYPE, categoryModel.getCategoryType());

        long CategoryId = db.insert(TABLE_CATEGORY, null, values);
        db.close();
        return CategoryId;
    }
```

and Finally my **getCategoryByType()** method on My **Database**.

```
public ArrayList<CategoryModel> getCategoryByType(int CategoryType) {
        ArrayList<CategoryModel> Categories = new ArrayList<>();
        // String selectQuery = "SELECT " + CATEGORY_NAME + " FROM " + TABLE_CATEGORY + " WHERE " + CATEGORY_TYPE + " = " + CategoryType;
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CATEGORY + " WHERE " + CATEGORY_TYPE + " = " + CategoryType + " ORDER BY CategoryId DESC";
        Log.e(DB_LOG, selectQuery);
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    CategoryModel categoryModel = new CategoryModel();

                    categoryModel.setCategoryId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(CATEGORY_ID)));
                    categoryModel.setCategoryName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CATEGORY_NAME)));
                    categoryModel.setCategoryType(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CATEGORY_TYPE)));

                    Categories.add(categoryModel);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        return Categories;
    }
```

Any Type of Help, Suggestion is much Appreciated.....Thanks in advance

Below is Screenshot after adding First Item.

[First Item Inserted but not shown in RecycleView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfV45.png)

My LogCat Screenshot is below.

[Logcat Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptjFD.png)

Comment: have you tried running a debugger through the getCategoryByType code?

Comment: yes....i tried...it too..also in Log.e  and Toast as well.

Comment: i think it seems problem in getCategoryByType()... because  of  do{}while();  loop...it dont refreshed first item because of do.while....do is execute first without any condition.

Comment: @ Zharf bro... excepting one item on ArrayList<>  all another items is  refreshing after inserting...have you seen any error.

Comment: try use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); ` in your `CategoryListActivity.onCreate` function inside your `if`. i hope it would work if there is no bug in your `getCategoryByType` function.

Comment: ok i am doing this.

Comment: you told about inside this if(allCategory.size() > 0) {} loop......???

Comment: yes. in that if after this line `recyclerCategory.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: no. bro.  it not worked...i added your Name as Category but it did not. refreshing...see i edited my Que. i put screen shot with Category of Your Name

Comment: where did you add your `toast` code that is show categories in your screenshot?

Comment: i added Toast  in  myDb.createCategory(categoryModel);  after this Line  but  i removed it while asking Question.

Comment: why use reinialize your adapter after `allCategory.addAll(myDb.getCategoryByType(CategoryType));`? you just need `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` without recreate Adapter and set in `RecyclerView`

Comment: now see. i updated  my Que.... i hope you can give my Ans. bcz you have an Experience...and you have more knowledge. i read in your profile.. Thanks.. i gave 2  days for this problem. but my senior was also unable to find solution...and sorry for my English

Comment: @anatoli you told well ....i did it....but when i write only single Line...adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();....it gave me null pointerexception...i dont know how it gave null pointer. my Arraylist size is become 1 after inserting First item...but it not worked

Comment: are you sure that after `allCategory.addAll(myDb.getCategoryByType(CategoryType));` your `allCategory` has data?

Comment: yes after this Line. i have all Category Data on allCategory. i will put my Logcat for 2 to 3 minutes.

Comment: @SagarAghara, you have not initalized you `RecyclerView` with `LinearLayout`. your `RecyclerView` needs `LayoutManager` to know how show the data. If `if (allCategory.size() > 0)` is false the Layout initialisation for `RecyclerView` will never come

Comment: see my Logcat Screenshot. after inserting 1st category.

Comment: it  seems now i have to change my RecycleView to ListView...):

Comment: @ pooyan.....you will check my  getCategoryByType()  one time please whenever you will be free.. if any problem on that..for fetching first row from cursor....Thanks

Comment: @SagarAghara see if i understand your problem in right way : you run your activity, there is no categories, you add first one,but your RecyclerView not updated, you add second category, and now your RecyclerView  is updated.

Comment: yes...but  after adding first  categories  all next will be updated..only when i came back on my Activity.

Comment: See my all Steps i add in my Question....see i declered 3 steps in my Que.

Comment: instead of `allCategory = myDb.getCategoryByType(CategoryType);` make `allCategory.allAll(myDb.getCategoryByType(CategoryType));`

Comment: ok....i m doing\

Comment: @SagarAghara your `getCategoryByType()` seems ok. and also according to what you said it doesn't seems that your problem comes from your database code.

Comment: yes. not more but i am also very few experts in sqlite.  but problem is occur though....(:

Comment: @pooyan...now solved it...Thank you for your valuable response...Thanks  to  all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your `onCreate` in this way

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_category);

    myDb = new MyDatabase(this);
    recyclerCategory = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerCategory);

     CategoryType = CaseActivity.CategoryType;
     Log.d(GlobalConstant.KEY_CATEGORY_TYPE, "" + CategoryType);

     allCategory = myDb.getCategoryByType(CategoryType);

     if (allCategory.size() == 0) {
         Toast.makeText(this, "No Category", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }    

    adapter = new CategoryAdapter(allCategory);
    recyclerCategory.setAdapter(adapter);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerCategory.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerCategory.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerCategory.setHasFixedSize(true);
}
```

and now you can use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` without recreation of `adapter` and set them to `RecyclerView`

if you make in `setPositiveButton` `allCategory = myDb.getCategoryByType(CategoryType);` then your reference to `allCategory` is lost.

you need instead

```
allCategory.clear();
allCategory.addAll(myDb.getCategoryByType(CategoryType));
```

Comment: see i did as i say..i did +1 on your answer...i can not Accept answer bcz of few reputation as you know.

Comment: I'm glad that could help

Comment: yup...you and @Rahul saved my day..Tnx i will never forget it.

Comment: i have 4 Recyclerview in my App. with Refreshing problem...you had not solve my 1 Problem...but you released me from my 4 problems.

Comment: bro..what if i write allCategory.addAll(myDb.getCategoryByType(CategoryType));.... in my onCreate instead of....allCategory = myDb.getCategoryByType(CategoryType);

Comment: @SagarAghara, then you receive `NullPointerException` because `allCategory` is still not initialized. You can make `allCategory = ArrayList<>();` and then `allCategory.addAll(myDb.getCategoryByType(CategoryType));`. `allCategory` must be initialized only once to not loose reference to object

Comment: okok now got it...Thanks bro....means initializatin is important at all.

Answer (score 1):

Change your Activity onCreate:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_category);

        myDb = new MyDatabase(this);
        recyclerCategory = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerCategory);

        CategoryType = CaseActivity.CategoryType;
        Log.d(GlobalConstant.KEY_CATEGORY_TYPE, "" + CategoryType);
        allCategory = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new CategoryAdapter(allCategory);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerCategory.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerCategory.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerCategory.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerCategory.setAdapter(adapter);

        allCategory = myDb.getCategoryByType(CategoryType);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChange();

        if (allCategory.size() == 0) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "No Category", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }    
    }
```

and inside **setPositiveButton**, replace

```
adapter = new CategoryAdapter(allCategory);
recyclerCategory.setAdapter(adapter);

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

with

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Also replace

```
allCategory = myDb.getCategoryByType(CategoryType);
```

with

```
allCategory.addAll(myDb.getCategoryByType(CategoryType));
```

And try to run your program again.

Comment: @anatoli...where you go..come back your idea refreshing my categories now..plz post your answer again with few info.i will accept it ..Tnx.

Comment: ohhh sorry i dont have enough reputation to accept it....and vote up too.but i will do it using my second account.

Comment: accept an answer you can after 48 hours after question start. No reputation is needed.

Comment: ok..then i will accept it tomorrow....bro  i will do as you will say....(: